# How to get point position in the grid by using dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, unity-game-engine, grid, point

can someone help me?
I made a grid for my board. When I'm trying to get Point position of the square in the board, console returns only (0,0).

This is my point code:

```
public struct Point 
{
    public int X {get; set;}
    public int Y {get; set;}

    public Point(int x, int y){
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;

    }


}
```

This is script where every square get a point in the grid when instantiated:

```
public Point GridPosition { get; set; }


public void Setup(Point gridPos, Vector3 worldPos)
{
    this.GridPosition = gridPos;
    transform.position = worldPos;
}

private void OnMouseDown(){

    Debug.Log (GridPosition.X + ", "+ GridPosition.Y );

}
```

And this is my main script with Dictionary part:

```
public static Dictionary<Point,Grid> Tiles { get; set; }

void Start()
{
    CreateLevel ();
}

void CreateLevel()
{

    Tiles = new Dictionary<Point,Grid> ();
}

private void PlaceTilesColliders(Vector3 tileStart, float tileOffset){

    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) 
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) 
        {

            TileCollider.GetComponent<Grid> ().Setup (new Point (x, y), new Vector3 (tileStart.x + (tileOffset * x), tileStart.y - (tileOffset * y), 0));

            Tiles.Add (new Point (x, y), Instantiate(TileCollider).GetComponent<Grid>());


        }
    }  
}
```

So, console return every time (0,0), don't matter which square was clicked.
Can someone explain me how to get true point position of the square in the grid?

Comment: inscope studios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

avariant is essentially correct with their answer, but I'd like to point out what your code is *actually doing* and why you're getting the values you're getting.

Lets look at this loop:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)  {
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)  {
        TileCollider.GetComponent<Grid> ().Setup (new Point (x, y), new Vector3 (tileStart.x + (tileOffset * x), tileStart.y - (tileOffset * y), 0));
        Tiles.Add (new Point (x, y), Instantiate(TileCollider).GetComponent<Grid>());
    }
}
```

We loop over Y and X (this is fine) and then we call `TileCollider.GetComponent<Grid> ()`. Wait, hold on, `TileCollider`? What is this? This can't be one of our files in the scene, we haven't used our X and Y coordinates to go *fetch* a GameObject from the scene to get this reference...

That means *anything we do to it has no effect on our tiles in the game world!* And because the reference isn't updated, we continuously update it's values to the new X and Y positions, overwriting what we'd already done and having no effect on anything.

Oops.

And this is why avariant says that you need to call `Instantiate` and create a new tile, then get the component from that GameObject and call `Setup()` on it.

Comment: Oh, thanks for description, i don't even remarked it... It's looks so weird when you just missed things like this

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept an answer (and once you have 15 rep, you can upvote too).

Comment: You guys helped me, Avariant have short answer about problem, but your answer was with detailed description of my mistake, i cant choice what is better for other guys who will meet with a similar problem xD

Comment: It is your choice!

Answer (score 1):

Try `Instantiate` first, then configure the resulting new Grid and add to the dictionary.

```
for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) 
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) 
        {

            GameObject newGrid = Instantiate(TileCollider);
            newGrid.GetComponent<Grid>().Setup(new Point (x, y), new Vector3 (tileStart.x + (tileOffset * x), tileStart.y - (tileOffset * y), 0));

            Tiles.Add(new Point (x, y), newGrid.GetComponent<Grid>());
        }
    }
```

I would recommend, though, that you pay attention to parenting, as right now the instantiated objects have no parent.

Comment: Thank you! When i have tried to add a parent object to my tile objects with previous code, unity gave me an error